# Accessing child properties from a dictionary, which stores parent class type

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I would like to create a dictionary that can hold parent and child types. I would like to store different child types and be able to call their data.

The problem I am running in to is that when pulling the objects out of the dictionary, they are treated as their parent type, since the dictionary type is set as the parent object. The only way I have figured out to access their additional properties is through instantiating a new object with var (see below).

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Also, if my lingo/terminology is incorrect, please feel free to correct me as I am trying to learn. Thanks!

Update: I have updated my code slightly to try to convey exactly what I am trying to do. (added the foreach loop).

```
        public class parent
        {
            public string name;     
        }

        public class child : parent 
        {
           public int age;      
        }

        public class library
        {               
        }

        public class Program
        {
           public static void Main(string[] args)
           {                
              Dictionary<int, parent> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, parent>();
              child child1 = new child();
              child child2 = new child();

              child1.age = 5;
              child2.age = 10;

              dictionary.Add(1,child1);
              dictionary.Add(2,child2);    


     foreach(KeyValuePair<int, parent> d in dictionary)  
    {

    Console.WriteLine(d.age);

    }                  


          }
}
```

Comment: Even though your code shows the objects and types involved it really doesn't show the issue you're having. It is proper etiquette to show the minimal amount of code that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of accessing just the `child` members of the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, parent> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, parent>();
child child1 = new child();
child child2 = new child();

child1.age = 5;
child2.age = 10;

dictionary.Add(1,child1);
dictionary.Add(2,child2);
dictionary.Add(45, new parent());

foreach(var c in dictionary.Select(x => x.Value).OfType<child>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.age);
}
```

That gets me just `5` & `10` and ignores the `parent` object I put in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is likely wrong if you are doing this, but you already have it correct.

```
var child1a = child1 as child;
```

Does **not** instantiate a new object. It simply downcasts to the `child` type. Downcasting is a code-smell, so consider re-working your design to where this isn't necessary.

Also, `as` will return `null` if the cast fails, so you should be checking it:

```
var child1a = child1 as child;

if (child1a != null)
  Console.WriteLine(child1a.age);
```

Finally, you never *actually* used the dictionary in your code, you likely wanted to do:

```
var child1a = dictionary[1] as child;

if (child1a != null)
  Console.WriteLine(child1a.age);
```

To your update, that loop will *never* work (nor should it). Not all the objects in your collection are guaranteed to have the "age" property.

With respect to your loop, you *can* do this:

```
foreach (child item in dictionary.Values)
{
    ...
}
```

or:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, parent> kvp in dictionary)
{ 
   if (kvp.Value is child)
   {
       child item = (child)kvp.Value;
       ...
   }
}
```

Which will pull out the `child` items from your values collection and let you use them as such. If thats all you are doing though, a `Dictionary` is *way* overkill here.

Comment: You are right. I had actually meant to put "var child1a = new child1 as child;" when I meant instantiate a new object. However, I am still looking for a solution to getting the object out of the dictionary as a child object. I will update my code, but what I am looking to do is pull each item out of the dictionary and access the child properties. Thank you.

Comment: @parrotsnest I will update my answer to include this, but you simply **cannot** do that. If you stored it as the base class, it will come out that way, end of story. You have to cast to get at the derived properties. The fact that this is necessary means you probably set up your design incorrectly. Fixing your design is the *real* solution.

Comment: @parrotsnest Also, `var child1a = new child1 as child` makes no sense at all, and wouldn't compile. Regardless, instantiation is *not* what you are looking for here, as it appears you have figured out.

Comment: Awesome. Those solutions are definitely helpful. I will re-evaluate my design with your feedback. Thanks so much!